# Is this function strongly convex? approaching boundary case

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

The definition for strongly convex is:
A differentiable function $f$ is strongly convex if
$$
f(y) \geq f(x)+\nabla f(x)^{T}(y-x)+\frac{\mu}{2}\|y-x\|^{2}
$$
for some $\mu>0$ and all $x, y$.

And for this function:
$$f(x) = sin(x),~~ x\in(\pi, 2\pi)$$

One way to see this is to calculate the second derivative, which is $-\sin (x)$ and that you cannot lower bound on the lower bound as $\sin (\pi)=\sin (2 \pi)=0$. But the region for this function does not contain $\pi$ and $2\pi$ which confuses me.

Comment: *hint:* try graphing the 2nd derivative over $(-\pi,2\pi)$ and looking at its sign.

Comment: If the inequality holds in $(\pi,2\pi)$ then it holds in $[\pi,2\pi]$ by continuity.

Comment: @geetha290krm How to tell if it holds in $(\pi, 2\pi)$?